# List item deleted and is not in Recycle Bin

Tags: 2010, list-item, recycle-bin

A list item has been deleted (less than 30 days ago) and it's not in the Recycle Bin. There are other items in the Recycle Bin from before and after this list item was deleted. I don't think the users can access the Recycle Bin/know where to find the Recycle Bin. I have looked through the remaining list items and the ID is missing so I don't think the item was overwritten/changed to the point I wouldn't recognise it.

- Is there a way of deleting something and bypassing the Recycle Bin?
- How else could this list item be missing?

I need to find out how this list item is dissapearing. It has happened before and we need the data back

Comment: Do you want to delete the item without storing the deleted item to recycle bin?

Comment: or do you want to find the missing item from recycle bin?

Comment: Sorry I've clarified. I want to find it

Comment: Are you very very sure it is deleted and not a View setting which hides the Item

Comment: Definitely sure, have even deleted the view and re-created it

Comment: If you tried all the below answers and if not sure whether item is deleted or not, i will suggest you export the list to excel and check whether item exist in excel.

Comment: If it exist in excel means there to be some issue with index columns.

Comment: Nope it's not in Excel

Comment: Have you got your deleted item?

Comment: No still not found it

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked in Second level Recycle Bin? Kindly Check at this location

**Site Setting** --> **SiteCollection Administartion Tab** --> **Recycle Bin**.

According to me, If Unique Permission is provided to the user for particular list and user does not have same rights over that site then deleted data resides into second level site collection and if user have same permission to that list as of at site level then it goes to First level Recycle Bin which can be seen at Site Contents

Comment: I don't have the power to see this Recycle Bin, I will see if I can find someone who does

Comment: Right someone else has checked there and it isn't there either :(

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that it was deleted by code?

If the programmer uses `SPListItem.Delete()` the item is gone and will not show up in recycle bin.

An alternative would be to call `SPListItem.Recycle()`.

Comment: Hmm..unlikely. No-one using this site has that kind of knowledge (including me) but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Are you looking at the correct site? Recycle Bin in SharePoint is site-specific, a document deleted from
>      http://myportal/sites/projects/manhattan will not appear in the top
>      level site’s (http://myportal/sites/projects) Recycle Bin.
> 2. Were it you who deleted the document? Recycle Bin is not only site-specific, it is also specific for each user. Thus the Recycle Bin
>      contents you see is limited to documents, items, lists and libraries
>      that you’ve deleted, content deleted by other users does not show up
>      here.
> 3. How long ago was it deleted?  Recycle Bin does not keep deleted items for ever. The default setting in SharePoint is to keep content
>      in Recycle Bin for 30 days after deletion, this can be changed by the
>      SharePoint farm administrators. When this grace period is over, items
>      are moved to the second stage aka Site Collection Recycle Bin.
>
> If any of the above seems to be the likely reason, the Site Collection
>   Recycle Bin can help. To access this, you should have the site
>   collection administrator privileges. Site Collection Recycle Bin shows
>   all the deleted content from all sub-sites within this site
>   collection, regardless of who deleted this data. By default it keeps
>   the data for the same period after it was moved from the first stage
>   Recycle Bin, or until it reaches certain percentage of the site
>   collection’s quota. Still there can be situations when a deleted
>   item/document does not appear in both site and site collection Recycle
>   Bins. The most common is when a folder or entire list or library is
>   deleted. Recycle Bin only shows the object that has been deleted, with
>   no ability to expand or search its contents. When looking for a
>   document make sure you consider that possibly its parent folder or
>   library can be showing up in the Recycle Bin instead.

Comment: 1. Yes definitely on the right site 2. No I did not delete it. I didn't know the Recycle Bin was person-specific, that is frustrating 3. Less than 30 days, I will add this clarification to my original post

Comment: Now you do have only option to check it in the site collection recycle bin. If its there than you can restore it otherwise you will not get it.

Comment: I've asked someone else to check there and it isn't there either

Comment: Than it's deleted permanently.. you might want to extend your deployment with the MSIT Site Delete Capture tool (available at http://governance.codeplex.com/), or looks for 3rd party granular recovery tools.

Comment: is that issue resolved?